# preventing sessions from recreating for a page

Tags: php, session, yii

I have developed a page. Whenever the user visits that page, a session is created. Now if the user opens the same page in two different tabs of the browser, then two sessions with different names are created.

I am using

```
public function actionSessionCreate(){
    do {
        $sessionName=  uniqid();
    }while (isset(Yii::app()->session[$sessionName]));
    Yii::app()->session[$sessionName]='any value';
}
```

for creating the session names.
Till now its working fine.
But the problem i can forsee is that if the user just refreshes the page, then also it will create a new session for that. And also if the user just moves back and forth , a new session will be created again and again.
**So how can i resolve this issue?**

`My logic:-`  I am thinking of sending an identifier in the URL which will be used when creating the session name. SO if the user just refreshes the same page, it will check for any session Name that includes the identifier. If it finds it, it will not create a session. Otherwise it will create it.

**Should I go with this logic? Or I should not play with sessions like this?**

Comment: did you check session before creating new one?

Comment: i cant check the name of the session as the session name is not passed from one page to another. It is created on that page only and that too with unique name. When the user refreshes the page, I lose the name of the session too.

Comment: id Your controllers and actions have a unique name, you can use them

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
if(!Yii::app()->user->hasState($sessionName)){   //checking whether the session occurs

    Yii::app()->user->setState($sessionName,"value");   //setting the session variable

}
```

For accessing session variable

```
Yii::app()->user->getState($sessionName);
```